# Sleeping Threadpool: worker thread awakens without notify() from main thread

Tags: multithreading, c++11, threadpool, mutex

I am implementing a thread pool where workers sleep when there is no work ready, and the main thread sleeps when workers are busy.
I noticed the worker threads are proceeding to work after calling `wait()` even though the main thread did not `notify_all()`.

The output looks something like below:

```
WORKER WAIT
MAIN SETUP
MAIN POLLS READINESS
WORKER WAIT
WORKER WAIT
WORKER AWAKENS!
WORKER START
ALL WORKERS READY
WORKER AWAKENS!
......
```

Worker function:

```
void TaskSystemParallelThreadPoolSleeping::waitFunc() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(*this->mutex_);
    while(true) {
        this->num_wait++;
        std::cout << "WORKER WAIT" << std::endl;
        this->cond_->wait(lock,
                        std::bind(&TaskSystemParallelThreadPoolSleeping::wakeWorker, this));
        std::cout << "WORKER AWAKENS!" << std::endl;
        if (this->done_flag == true) {
            this->mutex_->unlock();
            break;
        }
        this->mutex_->unlock();

        std::cout << "WORKER START" << std::endl;
        while (true) {
            this->mutex_->lock();

            if (this->not_done == 0) {  // ALL work done
                if (this->total_work != 0) {  // 1st time seen by workers
                    this->total_work = 0;
                    this->num_wait = 0;
                    std::cout << "WORKER WAKE MAIN" << std::endl;
                    this->mutex_->unlock();
                    this->cond_->notify_all();
                }
                this->mutex_->unlock();
                break;
            }

            int total = this->total_work;
            int id = this->work_counter;
            if (id == total) {  // NO work initiated or NO work left
                this->mutex_->unlock();
                continue;
            }

            ++(this->work_counter);  // increment counter
            this->mutex_->unlock();  // Let others access counters to work

            this->runnable->runTask(id, total); // do work

            this->mutex_->lock();
            --(this->not_done); // decrement counter after work done
            this->mutex_->unlock();
        }
        std::cout << "WORKER DONE" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "WORKER TERMINATE" << std::endl;
}
```

Main thread:

```
void TaskSystemParallelThreadPoolSleeping::run(IRunnable* runnable, int num_total_tasks) {
    //
    // TODO: CS149 students will modify the implementation of this
    // method in Part A.  The implementation provided below runs all
    // tasks sequentially on the calling thread.

    // Set-up work
    this->mutex_->lock();
    std::cout << "MAIN SETUP" << std::endl;
    this->runnable = runnable;
    this->work_counter = 0;
    this->not_done = num_total_tasks;
    this->total_work = num_total_tasks;

    // Tell workers there is work
    std::cout << "MAIN POLLS READINESS" << std::endl;
    while (this->num_wait < this->num_T) {  // Check if all ready
        this->mutex_->unlock();
        this->mutex_->lock();
    }
    std::cout << "ALL WORKERS READY" << std::endl;
    this->mutex_->unlock();
    this->cond_->notify_all();

    // Wait for workers to complete work
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(*this->mutex_);
    this->cond_->wait(lock,
                    std::bind(&TaskSystemParallelThreadPoolSleeping::wakeMain, this));
    std::cout << "MAIN END" << std::endl;
}
```

Condition to wake worker:

```
bool TaskSystemParallelThreadPoolSleeping::wakeWorker() {
    return (this->done_flag == true ||
                    (this->total_work != 0 && this->num_wait == this->num_T));
}
```

Condition to wake main thread:

```
bool TaskSystemParallelThreadPoolSleeping::wakeMain() {
    return this->total_work == 0;
}
```

Thread Pool Constructor:

```
TaskSystemParallelThreadPoolSleeping::TaskSystemParallelThreadPoolSleeping(int num_threads): ITaskSystem(num_threads) {
    //
    // TODO: CS149 student implementations may decide to perform setup
    // operations (such as thread pool construction) here.
    // Implementations are free to add new class member variables
    // (requiring changes to tasksys.h).
    //
    this->num_T = std::max(1, num_threads - 1);
    this->threads = new std::thread[this->num_T];
    this->mutex_ = new std::mutex();
    this->cond_ = new std::condition_variable();

    this->total_work = 0;
    this->not_done = 0;
    this->work_counter = 0;
    this->num_wait = 0;
    this->done_flag = {false};

    for (int i = 0; i < this->num_T; i++) {
        this->threads[i] = std::thread(&TaskSystemParallelThreadPoolSleeping::waitFunc, this);
    }
}
```

Thread pool destructor:

```
TaskSystemParallelThreadPoolSleeping::~TaskSystemParallelThreadPoolSleeping() {
    this->done_flag = true;
    this->cond_->notify_all();

    for (int i = 0; i < this->num_T; i++) {
        this->threads[i].join();
    }

    delete this->mutex_;
    delete[] this->threads;
    delete this->cond_;
}
```

I think the beginning should be:

```
WORKER WAIT
MAIN SETUP
MAIN POLLS READINESS
WORKER WAIT
WORKER WAIT
ALL WORKERS READY
WORKER AWAKENS!
WORKER START
WORKER AWAKENS!
......
```

Ie. workers should only awaken after main's `notify_all()`

EDIT:
Here's the full log. It seems this self-awakening of workers causes a deadlock later, where one of the workers awakens by itself and does all the work, setting `this->num_wait=0` and `this->total_work=0`. Therefore all the threads only see `this->num_wait=1`.

```
WORKER WAIT
MAIN SETUP
MAIN POLLS READINESS
WORKER WAIT
WORKER WAIT
WORKER AWAKENS!
WORKER START
ALL WORKERS READY
WORKER AWAKENS!
WORKER START
WORKER AWAKENS!
WORKER START
WORKER WAKE MAIN
WORKER DONE
WORKER WAIT
MAIN ENDWORKER DONE
WORKER WAIT
WORKER DONE
WORKER WAIT

MAIN SETUP
MAIN POLLS READINESS
ALL WORKERS READY
WORKER AWAKENS!
WORKER START
WORKER AWAKENS!
WORKER AWAKENS!
WORKER START
WORKER START
WORKER WAKE MAIN
WORKER DONE
WORKER WAIT
WORKER DONEMAIN END
MAIN SETUP
MAIN POLLS READINESS
WORKER DONE
WORKER WAIT

WORKER WAIT
WORKER AWAKENS!
WORKER START
ALL WORKERS READY
WORKER AWAKENS!
WORKER START
WORKER AWAKENS!
WORKER START
WORKER WAKE MAIN
WORKER DONEWORKER DONE
WORKER WAIT

WORKER WAIT
WORKER DONE
WORKER WAIT
MAIN END
MAIN SETUP
MAIN POLLS READINESS
ALL WORKERS READY
WORKER AWAKENS!
WORKER START
WORKER AWAKENS!
WORKER START
WORKER AWAKENS!
WORKER START
WORKER WAKE MAIN
WORKER DONE
WORKER WAIT
WORKER DONEWORKER DONE
WORKER WAIT
MAIN END
MAIN SETUP
MAIN POLLS READINESS

WORKER WAIT
WORKER AWAKENS!
WORKER START
WORKER WAKE MAIN
WORKER DONE
WORKER WAIT
ALL WORKERS READY
MAIN END
MAIN SETUP
MAIN POLLS READINESS
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for "worker thread awakens without notify from main thread" is pretty self-evident: the increment of this->num_wait and this->cond_->wait is within the same block without giving up the lock/notifying the main thread if condition variable wake up condition is true. The last thread in the poll passes the condition defined in wakeWorker() straightaway, hence your observation.

(I hope this code is just some toy code to play with -- it has too many issues ...  it doesn't surprise me if it gets deadlocked given the manual mutex lock/unlock ...)

```
        this->num_wait++;
        std::cout << "WORKER WAIT" << std::endl;
        this->cond_->wait(lock,
                        std::bind(&TaskSystemParallelThreadPoolSleeping::wakeWorker, this));
        std::cout << "WORKER AWAKENS!" << std::endl;
```

According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait, condition_variable::wait() is equivalent to

```
while (!pred()) {
    wait(lock);
}
```

so if pred() return true, the execution doesn't give up lock

Comment: why does the last thread pass the check straightaway? shouldn't it release the lock and then go to sleep due to the wait()?

Comment: according to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait, condition_variable::wait() is equivalent to 
while (!pred()) {
    wait(lock);
}. I.e. It checks the condition first and releases lock if pred() is false

Comment: @KcAble You can't wait if the thing you would be waiting for has already happened!

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Sorry, which part are you referring to?

Comment: @KcAble The last thread passes the check straightaway because it's waiting for something that has already happened. The `wait` function will not wait if the thing you ask it to wait for has already happened -- that could result in waiting forever.